# Identification of salts observed in steam vaporiser

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, precipitation, salt

[image]

Recently I observed some precipitated salts in steam vaporizer after completion of vaporization.

I am guessing that some of the white particles may be calcium carbonate ($\ce {CaCO3}$) formed from calcium bicarbonate dissolved in water by the reaction

$$\ce {Ca(HCO3)2(aq) \rightarrow CO2(g) + H2O(l) + CaCO3(s)}$$

I am curious to know what may be the other salts and how are they formed.

Comment: I don't think we would be able to adequately answer this, too many unknowns. Besides, what makes you think it's salt? From the look of it, it might be rust, particles of tubing/paint/ion exchange resin or who knows what else.

Comment: The only way for answering your question is to make a qualitative analysis of this substance. You would need a lab, some glassware and some chemicals: Without our knowing if you have got this material, we cannot do much more.

Comment: As complete vaporization was done, there would be salts from both carbonate and permanent hardness and also other salts, mostly sodium ones, aside of minor constituents.

Comment: You might get quite close to the composition of the deposit by reading the bottle label or by searching data about the water delivered by your municipality or the company serving you.